# WSO2 IWA with Kerberos – unable to decrypt kerberos token exception

Tags: kerberos, wso2-identity-server

We are using WSO2 5.4.1 version and trying to setup IWA using Kerberos. We have done all the configurations as mentioned in the following post.
  https://medium.com/@farasath/integrated-windows-authentication-with-kerberos-and-wso2-identity-server-ffcd8263a0f1

When we try to access the application we are getting following exception.

[image]
We have checked all the configurations multiple times but not able to figure out the root cause.  Can someone help us to find out what could be missing in this setup? Are we missing any additional step?

We have also tried with WSO2 IS version 5.5.0 but still getting same error. 
How can we enable additional logging to see what is going wrong with kerberos token decryption?

Comment: This could be related to the jdk issue https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8078439 based on the error message i see in your stacktrace "Unable to decrypt the kerberos ticket as context was not established"

Answer (score 0):

It was indeed a JDK issue. For some reason we were using Oracle jdk1.8.0_45 and we were facing this issue. We had upgraded the version to jdk1.8.0_162 and we were able to proceed but then we encounter another problem. After authentication we were not getting remote claims in the response from WSO2 IS. As per this post (stackoverflow.com/questions/49997900/…) we upgraded to latest patch of WSO2 IS 5.5.0 and now it is working.
We are able to authenticate user using IWA-Kerberose.